# groupBy is removing eager loaded relations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This works (Version A):

```
$applications=  Apply::with('user','newUser', 'requests.files', 'requests.mails', 'requests.rank.orgas', 'requests.mode.trainer')->get();
dd($applications);
```

Here is the output with all relations:

[image]

Now I would like to order the `Apply` models by latest `request.updated_at`. To do so, I added this (Version B):

```
$application = Apply::with('user','newUser', 'requests.files', 'requests.mails', 'requests.rank.orgas', 'requests.mode.trainer')
                                ->join('applyRequest', 'applyRequest.apply_id', '=', 'apply.id')
                                ->groupBy('apply.id')
                                ->orderByRaw('max(applyRequest.updated_at) desc')
                                ->get();
```

This resolves into the correct sql

```
"select * from `apply` inner join `applyRequest` on `applyRequest`.`apply_id` = `apply`.`id` group by `apply`.`id` order by max(applyRequest.updated_at) desc"
```

and the `Apply` models are correctly sorted. However, most relationships are not loaded anymore:

[image]

Basicly, only relation `user` is eager loaded, and the other relations `newUser` and `requests.*` are not loaded in version B (but in version A).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `join` on an eloquent model some unusual things can happen if you have columns that are the same in both tables (typically `id`).

My hunch is that your eager loading is happening on the `applyRequest` table id and not the `apply` table id as eloquent (for whatever reason) is using the wrong id value to build the model.  This can result in your eager loads being either wrong or non existent.

You can test this by dumping the model twice, once with the join and once without the join and then compare the values.

```
dump(Apply::get());
dump(Apply::join('applyRequest', 'applyRequest.apply_id', '=', 'apply.id')->get());
```

If the values are different then try this:

```
$application = Apply::select('apply.*')
                   ->with('user','newUser', 'requests.files', 'requests.mails', 'requests.rank.orgas', 'requests.mode.trainer')
                   ->join('applyRequest', 'applyRequest.apply_id', '=', 'apply.id')
                   ->groupBy('apply.id')
                   ->orderByRaw('max(applyRequest.updated_at) desc')
                   ->get();
```

The new `select` function will mean the query will still join the data but only your columns from the apply table are retrieved which will prevent the wrong values being put into the model.